# popen vs system call from c++

Tags: c++, bash, system, popen

In my C++ program I need to execute a bash script. I need then to return the result obtained running the script in my c++ program.
I have two possibilities:

```
1. use system(script.sh). In script.sh I redirect the output in a file which is processd after I return to the c++ program.
2. use popen
```

I am interested which of this methods is preffered, considering that the output returned from script.sh could be big(100 M). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `system` the parent process is blocked until the child process terminates. The child process will run with full performance.

`popen` will start the child process, but not wait until it ended. So the parent process can continue to do whatever it wants while the child is running, it can for example read the output of the child process. The parent process can decide if it wants to read blocking or non-blocking from the child's output pipe, depending on how much other things the parent process has to do. The child will run in parallel and write its output to the pipe. It might be blocked when writing if the parent process is not reading from the pipe and the pipe's memory limit is reached. So the parent process should keep on reading the output.

The `system` approach is a bit simpler. But `popen` gives you the possibility to read the process's output while it is still running. And you don't need the extra file (space). So I'd use `popen`.

Comment: But if the output is big, the current c++ program it is not held by the popen process, while reading from the popen stream?

Comment: On the contrary - with `system`, the c++ program has to wait until the script is finished before it can continue, while with `popen` it can start reading the output as soon as the script writes it.

Comment: @georgiana_e: The other way around. The `popen`ed process will be held back by the calling process _if it does not read_ the output. Pipe buffers are of finite size (and of pathetically small size on some systems, prepare for a surprise if you port your application to Windows, for example). Once the pipe's buffer is full, the called program blocks.

Comment: @georgiana_e I updated my answer. I hope it's more clear now what the differences are.

Comment: What if the bash script prompts and the parent process reads from the popened file descriptor? Wouldn't that block the parent process as well?

Comment: @rstackhouse The parent process can either `select()` and only call `read` when data is available on the pipe. Or it can set the pipe to non-blocking mode so that `read` will return immediately if no data is available.

Comment: This is **not** true :  *"When using system **the parent process is blocked** until the child process terminates"*. ... I did check it. It certainly doesn't block the parent *process*. You might mean it blocks the *thread*, not the *process* itself?

Comment: @Nawaz You are right, in a multi threaded process only the thread calling `system` is blocked until the child process terminates.